# Error while installing Xdebug in PHP version 5.6.32

Tags: php, xdebug

I am new to PHP. I want to enable Xdebug in Eclipse IDE but when I check Xdebug for my version https://xdebug.org/wizard.php showing error:- here is what

```
Tailored Installation Instructions
Summary
Xdebug installed: no
Server API: Apache 2.0 Handler
Windows: yes - Compiler: MS VC11 - Architecture: x86
Zend Server: no
PHP Version: 5.6.32
Zend API nr: 220131226
PHP API nr: 20131226
Debug Build: no
Thread Safe Build: yes
Configuration File Path: C:\Windows
Configuration File: E:\xampp1\php\php.ini
Extensions directory: E:\xampp1\php\ext

PHP versions below 7.0 are not supported.
If you like Xdebug, and thinks it saves you time and money, please have a look at the donation page.
```

Please help to install Xdebug in Eclipse. I've installed XAMPP, Eclipse PDT PHP.

Answer (score 1):

**It seams your PHP Version is too low for xdebug:**

- Your PHP: "PHP Version: 5.6.32"
- xDebug log said: "PHP versions below 7.0 are not supported."

So, after you upgrade you PHP version and successfully install xdebug, you should see (example):

```
# php -v
HP 7.2.3 (cli) (built: Mar  8 2018 10:30:06) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2018, by Derick Rethans
    with Zend OPcache v7.2.3, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
```

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to update this question because it is still possible to install XDebug against 5.6 and may still be necessary for legacy applications.

The wizard won't help you if you need to install XDebug for an older version of PHP (<7); you'll have to read the documents and work out the process yourself.

At https://derickrethans.nl/xdebug-php5.html the author states that the older source is available for downloading and using with older versions of php, and that 2.5 is the last version to work with PHP 5.6. You can download xdebug 2.5 from  https://xdebug.org/download.php (or other versions as required).

The instructions on how to do this are on the XDebug website but maybe a little hard to grasp. A rough guide for installing installing on a CentOS 7.5 with Php 5.6 would be:

- wgets https://xdebug.org/files/xdebug-2.5.5.tgz
- tar -xvzf xdebug-2.6.0.tgz
- cd xdebug-2.6.0
- phpize [troubleshoot: yum install php-devel]
- ./configure --enable-xdebug
- make
- create a directory keep the xdebug module: mkdir /usr/php/xdebug/255
- cp modules/xdebug.so /usr/php/xdebug/255
- Find the active php.ini using php -i or phpinfo() in a script.
- Restart the webserver: sudo service httpd restart
- Make sure XDdebug is reported as enabled.
- Edit php.ini:  sudo nano /etc/php.ini
- Add (or whatever your preferred options are) to php.ini:

  zend_extension="/usr/php/xdebug/255/xdebug.so"

  xdebug.remote_enable=1

  xdebug.remote_autostart = 1

  xdebug.remote_port="9000"

  xdebug.remote_connect_back=on
- Configure your client to connect. I've had this working with vscode.

You can find more information at https://xdebug.org/docs/install.